# A difficult integral $\int\frac{x^2-1}{(x+1)^3\sqrt{1+3x^2+x^4}}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Well, here goes:

$$\int\frac{x^2-1}{(x+1)^3\sqrt{1+3x^2+x^4}}\,dx$$

I wrote down a solution ... I am mentioning the basic steps.

**a)** Apply the sub $x=1/t$ and get the integral into a much a better form.

**b)** In the nominator there appears to be the derivative of $t+1/t$ which is substituted and then the integral is reduced down to this $\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

However, well what I don't like to this problem is that from step **a)** to step **b)** by applying a suitable sub I get to add the two integrals since they have the same denominator. Is this acceptable?

Any other ideas on how to attack this integral which seems pretty tough to me.

Comment: If you sub $x=\tan t$ you get $$\int \frac{\sec t}{(1+\tan t)} dt$$ which may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Which in turn is $$\int \frac{1}{\cos t + \sin t} dt = A \int \sec (t + \phi) dt$$ so you can get the integral in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @nayrb Sub $x=\tan t$ where? In the original integral??

Comment: The second one in your answer since $\tan^2 t + 1 = \sec^2 t$.

Comment: Yes.. for the second one in my answer... sure that is the natural way to go.. But my question is if we can find alternate proof for the original integral.